# How to click on this web element using selenium webdriver?

Tags: html, selenium, webdriver, click

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7kgH.png)

How would you click on this particular item in selenium each time by having just the date you want as a variable? I have shown the item in the attached image of the HTML. It is a panel calendar, however, I can't find the item using by.ID, class, etc. I can Click on it by using XPath however how do I make it specific to the data? I would like to click on it based on the.

```
data-moment="2022-10-30"
```

currently I just have this:

```
### Gets Edge driver and doesnt need extension update
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=EdgeService(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(
    'https://teewire.net/granada/'
)
driver.maximize_window()
pause(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='gz-time-slot-calendar']/ul/li[4]/a").click()
pause(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your XPath to this:

```
data_moment = "2022-10-30"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f"//*[@id='gz-time-slot-calendar']//a[@data-moment='{data_moment}']").click()
```